# No rows being returned from dataset JUST on iOS using MVC 3

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, dataset

I have a model that returns a dataset to a view and builds a list. The crazy thing is that I have tested this code with IE, Safari on Mac and Windows, Chrome and Opera and all return data.  However, on the iPad or iPhone, zero rows are returned from the dataset object. It seems that the model is in fact passing the dataset to the view. I am using jquerymobile to render the view for the iOS devices and have taken that out of the mix to test and it still doesn't work. I am out of ideas. Anyone?

Here is the view code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ViewMasterPage1.Master"           Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <% Dim ds1 As DataSet = Model %>
        <li><%=Html.Label(ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count)%></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the controller pushing the data to the view:

```
Function CustomerShowSearch(ByVal searchterm As String) As ActionResult
    Dim searchcustomer As New GetCustomersModel
    Dim dataset As DataSet

    searchterm = Request("searchterm")
    dataset = searchcustomer.CustomerSearchResult(searchterm)

    ViewData.Model = dataset

    Return View()
End Function
```

Again ... a value is returned in EVERYTHING but iOS. Thanks in advance!

Here is the post form that calls the controller to display the view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%Using Html.BeginForm("CustomerShowSearch", "ShowCustomers", FormMethod.Post, New With  {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"})%> 

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">                          
            <label for="searchterm">Enter a name to search:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("searchterm", "", New With {.type = "search"})%>
            <br />
            <label for="statelist">Enter a state to search:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("statelist")%>
            <input type="submit" data-icon="search" value="Search" />
        </div>

    <% End Using %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: what is the html output when rendring the page on the iPad? do you know it's calling the serverside function at all?

Comment: Yes it is calling as I can just drop an html helper in there and it works fine.  In the example above, say all the browers will return say "5".  Meaning 5 rows returned from dataset.  iOS will return "0" every time.  The properties on the dataset object will return to iOS but not the rows.

Comment: are you using post or get? what does the html that the user clicks on to get to that page look like?

Comment: It is a post.  I added it above.

Comment: my guess is the enctype="multipart/form-data" is causing your issues, thought I don't know enough about it to post an answer

Comment: I have tried with an without.  It seems that the dataset has data but when the rows property is queried, it returns nothing.  ds1.tables(0).count does return 1 in iOS.  ds1.tables(0).rows.count returns 0 just on iOS.  Actual record count everywhere else.  Weird because this should be all server side.

Answer (score 0):

Found It!  Actually is was rather simple.  The safari mobile browser was adding spaces to the end of the post result.  Very strange.  Simply trim the values coming from the form and it works.